# Why does Hibernate open many ports to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I am working on a Spring Boot application with Vaadin and Hibernate, and I have a problem with hibernate MySQL, every time I query the database it open a new port to MySQL database.

when I execute `netstat -ano | grep 3306` I get this :

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62066        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62067        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62068        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62070        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62071        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62072        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62073        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62074        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62075        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62076        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62077        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62079        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62080        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62081        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62082        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62083        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62084        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62085        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62086        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62092        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62093        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62094        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62095        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62096        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62097        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62098        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62099        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62101        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62102        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     10956 .......
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide a query example? I mean method that opens the session issues the query and closes the session? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is beacause your ConnectionPoolManager creates such numer of connections that are resused by your application. Multiple connections allows your application to use DB in concurrent way. you can shrink that down using `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `persistance.xml`. On how to do that, you have to read the docs of `ConnectionPoolManager` you are using (either built-in or eg. `C3P0` )

You could try to share your configuration file for future assistance.

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss for your time, Can I you provide me a link on how we can do so?

Comment: @MounirBoussetta http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource here you have `Spring`s configuration but I cannot guarantee that this applies to you - you didnt mentioned anything about your current configuration (nor that you are using spring ;P)

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet I suppose that you open and close the session properly.
A Session retrieves a connection from the datasource if needed therefore it is crucial to close it once you are done with your actions.

If the connections that seem to be open increase then you have a connection leak.

If you see a steady number of connections open throughout your application's lifecycle, then you need to check your datasource configuration and how many connections are set to be open.

For example when it comes to c3p0 datasource
for
`cpds.setMinPoolSize(5)`

you are gonna have 5 connections open no matter what.

Comment: Thanks @gkatzioura , I will try c3p0

Comment: No need to change datasource. Just check how many connections you have set to be open mandatory according to your current datasource.

Comment: Is there a way to set connections number in spring buil-in application.properties ?

Comment: Yes check this link
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource
However not sure if it applies to your configuration

Comment: I tried c3p0 with this config but still the same issue:                           `@Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds= new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mdb?user=root&password=");
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cpds.setInitialPoolSize(1);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        cpds.setMinPoolSize(2);
        cpds.setCheckoutTimeout(300);
        cpds.setMaxStatements(50);

        cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(300);
        return cpds;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was in Hibernate, it doesn't close the session automatically, to fix the problem, I just set a `hibernate connection release mode`. For me, I set these hibernate properties in `application.properties` :

```
#hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_statement
```